# Reservation script impediments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Great people of stackoverflow,

We are trying to make a reservation system for a Theater. We used a script to make an array of the seatmap and give it a clickable function. After its selected the html table shows the count of the seats. What we want to achieve is that the table shows the price of the seats and counts them up. ( seat_1 = 7.50 /seat_2 = 11.00 / seat_3 = 13.00 ). But it looks like we are extremely stuck. We need to find a way to make the selected seats count up in total. our html file takes the variables but sees it as a single chair, which means we have to relate a price to the seat_1 or count_seat_1, for instance. we tried adding a price, and using a string method to detach the row and seat but this seems to fail aswell. After it shows the price, and count-up we need a button which leads us to a fresh page where the selected seats are summarized in for instance the same table but no longer changable. Sorry for the long story but we've been looking for days and cant find a decent way to do this with. Thank you in advance for your help, its greatly appreciated!
OUR COMPLETE CODE>
http://jsfiddle.net/2fr8vzub/

Kind regards, Michel.

```
var room1 = [
//   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //14
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //13
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //12
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], //11
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], //10
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //9
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //8
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //7
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], //5
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //4
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //3
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //1
];

function make_seat() {
  for (var r = 0; r < room1.length; r++) {

    var rowdiv = $("<div>");

    rowdiv.attr("id", "DIV_" + r);
    for (s = 0; s < room1[r].length; s++) {

        var seat = $("<button id='seat_"+r+"_"+s+"'>");

        seat.attr("id", "seat_" + r + "_" + s);

        switch(room1[r][s]) {
            case 1:
                seat.attr("id", "seat_" + r + "_" + s + "-" + 7.50);
                break;
            case 2:
                seat.attr("id", "seat_" + r + "_" + s + "-" + 11);
                break;
            case 3:
                seat.attr("id", "seat_" + r + "_" + s + "-" + 13); 
                break;
        }

        // seat.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
        //seat.addEventListener("click",reservation,false);


        seat.click(order);
        switch (room1[r][s]) {
            case 0:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_0");
                break;
            case 1:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_1");
                break;
            case 2:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_2");
                break;
            case 3:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_3");
                break;
        }
        rowdiv.append(seat);

    }

   $("#DIV_inhoud").append(rowdiv);
}

}


function order() {
  var seatInfo = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
  var r = seatInfo[1];
  var s = seatInfo[2];
//var p = ophalenPrijs("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $("#count_seat_1").html($(".seat_1.selected").size());
  $("#count_seat_2").html($(".seat_2.selected").size());
  $("#count_seat_3").html($(".seat_3.selected").size());
  $("#count_total").html($(".selected").size());
}


function start() {
   make_seat();

}
start();
```

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxsaaLqc/)?

Comment: Yes. that seems to fix the count problem. Thanks! it seems to work fine but now i need a way to import the table to a clean html page without the table being altered. In that way i can add a Random Number Generator which gives you a reservation code. (not the official way but it works for our purpose)